# Android camera preview whit png image over

Tags: android, camera

I want to start the camera and have over de preview one image as a frame ( some lines on a transparent background - a png file).

Can you help me ? Sone links. I try some example from this forum but it didnt work

Edit :

When i open the camera ( back camera ) i want to have over the preview the next png image ( only the frame should be visible...the background is transparent). To be able to fit the car in my frame and after i push a button ( or the preview ) to be able to save the image.

[image]

thanks

Comment: I dont understand your question would you mine re editing it?

Comment: Could you show us sites where you are following to do it ?